# Finding patterns in HEX data with regex but getting duplicates

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I have a regex python script to go over Hex data and find patterns which looks like this

```
r"(.{6,}?)\1{2,}"
```

all it does is look for at least 6 character long hex strings that repeat and at least have two instances of it repeating. My issue is it is also finding substrings inside larger strings it has already found for example:
if it was "a00b00a00b00a00b00a00b00a00b00a00b00" it would find 2 instances of "a00b00a00b00a00b00" and 6 instances of "a00b00" How could I go about keeping only the longest patterns found and ignoring even looking for shorter patterns without more hardcoded parameters?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fnmatch

pattern_string = "abcdefabcdef"

def print_pattern(pattern, num):
    n = num

    # takes n and splits it by that value in this case 6
    new_pat = [pattern[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(pattern), n)]
    # this is the hit counter for matches
    match = 0
    # stores the new value of the match
    new_match = ""
    #loops through the list to see if it matches more than once
    for new in new_pat:
        new_match = new
        print new
        #if matches previous keep adding to match
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(new, new_pat[0]):
            match += 1
    if match:
        print "Count: %d\nPattern:%s" %(match, new_match)
        #returns the match
        return new_match


print_pattern(pattern_string, 6)
```

regex is better but this was funner to write